# How can I list module's dependencies, including those needed only during testing?

Tags: perl, perl-module

From the [Mojolicious wiki](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/wiki/Database-support) on the topic of Database support:

> Although SQL::Abstract looks like having much more dependencies, they
>   are needed only during testing, so you can safely use the module with
>   your application in a shared(hostile) environment. Just unpack it in
>   your lib directory.

Is there any way I can list the dependencies needed only during testing (on a unix-like system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See key `build_requires` in the [distro meta file](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SQL-Abstract/META.yml) (specifications: [v1.4](http://module-build.sourceforge.net/META-spec-v1.4.html#build_requires), [v2](http://p3rl.org/CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aSpec#PREREQUISITES)).

If SQL-A would upgrade to META spec v2, you could distinguish between genuine build deps and test deps.

Comment: This works only for the distributions that use this relatively new feature in the build systems. I know you say as much, but I thought I'd say it in another way.